# Не загружается картинка через форму Django

Tags: python, django

Всех алоха, при попытки загрузить картинку, через форму ничего не выходит, но через админку все грузит.

**ССЫЛКА на GITHUB: https://github.com/DarAnod-B/site.git**

add_news.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block sidebar %}
{% include 'inc/_sidebar.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Добавление новости</h1>

<form action="{% url 'add_news' %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Добавить новость</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Bd


class NewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bd
        # fields = '__all__'
        fields = ['name', 'content', 'category', 'is_published', 'photo']
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Bd, Category


class BdAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'photo', 'category', 'is_published', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
    list_display_links = ('name', 'photo', 'category', 'is_published', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
    list_filter = ('updated_at', 'created_at')


class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title',)
    list_display_links = ('title',)
    search_fields = ('title',)
    list_filter = ('title',)


# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Bd, BdAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

ulrs.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='home'),
    # Создание переменной  category_id  с типом int, это число, которое передается через  url
    path('category/<int:category_id>/', get_category, name='category'),
    path('news/<int:news_id>/', view_news, name='view_news'),
    path('news/add-news/', add_news, name='add_news')
]
```

views.py

```
def add_news(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Bd.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = NewsForm()
    return render(request, 'bord/add_news.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Источник: https://qna.habr.com/q/9

Во-первых, `<form action="{% url 'add_news' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Во-вторых,
`form = NewsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)89357`